# JavaFX resize button in HBox FXML

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

So Im doing some app layout and I need to put two buttons on bottom of window. I want them also to resize whenever I change window size, is it possible to do it in SceneBuilder or modyfing fxml? I cannot find anything that would do it. I know its possible using code to bind widthProperty of parent to child but I want make it without it.

FXML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <left>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="170.0" style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 0 2 0 0;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ComboBox layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="170.0" />
            <RadioButton layoutY="27.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="RadioButton" />
            <RadioButton layoutY="51.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="RadioButton" />
            <RadioButton layoutY="74.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="RadioButton" />
            <Label alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutY="386.0" maxHeight="15.0" prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="170.0" style="-fx-background-color: violet;" text="Label" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </left>
   <center>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="165.0" prefWidth="330.0" promptText="WITAM" text="heh" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
            <HBox layoutX="14.0" layoutY="147.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="320.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
               <children>
                  <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" text="Button" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set [`HBox.hgrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) to [`ALWAYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Priority.html#ALWAYS) or [`SOMETIMES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Priority.html#SOMETIMES) (in the node) that the node can grow with the `HBox`. And you should ensure that the node can grow, for example the Button has a default maxWidth which is the computed size, so change it.

This is how it should look like:

```xml
<HBox>
    <children>
        <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" text="Button" />
    </children>
</HBox>
```